# What happens if one fills whole RAM with zeros

Tags: c++, ram

What will happen to PC, if one runs the code snippet?

```
...
for (char* ptr = 0; &*ptr < RAM_SIZE; ++ptr)
{
    *ptr = 0;
}
...
```

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Language rules aside, you should be aware that consumer operating systems separate your pointer values from actual RAM addresses via virtual memory.

Comment: @Galik, sure I didn't:) But I'm curious

Comment: Most environments won't let you do this (your app will crash/terminate on the first write attempt).

Comment: segfault, perhaps? because dereferencing 0?

Comment: You can't write to memory addresses that you haven't allocated through system calls. i.e. the internal calls of `new` or `malloc`

Comment: On any modern OS this code will crash without breaking anything. Because of [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), you won't be able to write to memory that doesn't belong to your process.

Comment: @vadixem "_sure I didn't:) But I'm curious_" What's stopping you from setting up the VM, and seeing how different OS's handle this, if you are scared of running such code on your real machine?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius true, I should've tried it.

Comment: In an embedded system, you may wind up writing to control registers of hardware devices and it could get ugly (a.k.a. undefined behavior).  You may write to locations that don't have any memory (read or read/write) assigned to them and thus generate data access aborts.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Also I was afraid what could happen to my PC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In practice, on a modern PC, with modern operating system, trying to write to memory address 0 will result in segmentation fault, and the operating system terminating the program.

On some embedded hardware, or PC with operating system without memory protection (such as MS-DOS), the computer would most likely hang quickly, because you would be overwriting memory areas important to the operating system, and CPU would end up executing "random" machine code, which would in most cases end up in CPU being "stuck" in some way. To recover, you might need hard reset or power-off. If you were less lucky, you could also end up corrupting for example your disk contents.

On a language level, assigning 0 to pointer is same as assigning a null pointer to it. Dereferencing null pointer (that `*ptr = 0;`) is undefined behavior, so in theory compiler could generate any machine code imaginable for that source code (because it can prove that you have undefined behavior right there). So in theory anything might happen when you run that.